# Enable Disable interrupt and thread safety

Tags: c, thread-safety, interrupt

What is the point of disabling interrupts before getting the results and clearing the Post_Bits to its original state `Post_Bits &= (~Post);` and testing the condition if the particular Post `res =  Post_Bits & Post;` was seen before.
For instance, if `Post_Bits` was used on another function and you are changing it here, does clearing it inside the disabling/Enable interrupt make it thread safe?

```
BOOL Post_a_Note(Post_t Post) // Post_t is a 32bit number
{
    Post_t res; //Final Result
    UINT16 capture = INTDisableInterrupts(); 
    res    =  Post_Bits & Post; 
    Post_Bits &= (~Post); 
    INTRestoreInterrupts(capture); 
    return (res != 0); 
}
```

Comment: Because if an interrupt occurs between lines 5 and 6, and sets the bit you are examining, you will clear the bit but report it as not set: therefore missing that event.

Comment: Interrupts are not threads, thread-safety is a different beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling interrupts is a simplest method to make sure that code fragment executed by only one thread at any time.